# Elastic search azure cluster prevent public write

Tags: azure, elasticsearch

We recently created one azure elastic search cluster. Everything around writing, querying, fail-over works fine. But cluster URL is public, from any machine I can write data to the index. What is the best way to secure the cluster and prevent it from writing data, only authenticated machine should be able to write data to index.

Thanks,
Manish